# SQL with HTTP/1.1 Get

Tags: php, http-1.1

This was reposted from [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98457/sql-insert-with-http1-1?noredirect=1#comment177644_98457).

Sorry for such an amateur question, but I have no idea why this does not work.
I have a "add.php" to connect to the MySQL server.

**/add.php**

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");

    $link=Connection();

    $ID1=$_POST["ID1"];
    $ID2=$_POST["ID2"];
    $ID3=$_POST["ID3"];
    $ID4=$_POST["ID4"];
    $ID5=$_POST["ID5"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO Battery (ID01, ID02, ID03, ID04, ID05) 
        VALUES ('".$ID1."','".$ID2.",'".$ID3.",'".$ID4."','".$ID5."')"; 

    mysql_query($query,$link);
    mysql_close($link);

    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php

    function Connection(){
        $server="mysql.randomserver.com";
        $user="random";
        $pass="1234";
        $db="random_1234";

        $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);

        if (!$connection) {
            die('MySQL ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($db) or die( 'MySQL ERROR: '. mysql_error() );

        return $connection;
    }
?>
```

I use a simple HTTP 1.1 protocol:

> GET /add.php?ID1=1int&ID2=2char&ID3=3char&ID4=4int&ID5=2015-04-13
>   01:00:00 HTTP/1.1\r\nmyhost\r\nContent-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n\r\n

where **ID1,ID4 is int; ID2, ID3 char; ID5 Datetime (SQL)**

The host throw me this error:

```
+IPD,168:<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>hosting</center>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone have any idea for me to try out, I would be grateful! I'm really clueless...

Fixed:
(moskito-x) **'".$ID3.",** to **'".$ID3."',**

## UPDATE:2015.04.22 13:56

Ok, I tried this and it works on my Main page: Index.php (just copy the whole /add.php code into /index.php)

```
$query= "INSERT INTO  Battery (ID01,ID02,ID03,ID04,ID05) 
        VALUES ('1int','2char','3char','4int','2015-04-22 17:20:28')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
```

But if I replace it into the add.php, no row is inserted.

I changed add.php as other have suggested:

**add.php**

```
<?php
    $link=Connection();
        $server="mysql.myhost.com";
        $user="randomUser";
        $pass="randomPwd";
        $db="radomdb";

    $link=mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);


    $query = "INSERT INTO  Battery (ID01,ID02,ID03,ID04,ID05)
        VALUES ('1int','2char','3char','4int','2015-04-22 17:20:28')";
    mysqli_query($link, $query)
             mysqli_close($link);
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure if your mysql_query syntax is correct: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php Do you have error reporting turned on for your php code ?

Comment: You're missing at least one `\n` in that `GET` command.

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_` functions are now no longer just discouraged (as it was over the last years), but officially [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). You should really use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), as this code will stop working very soon.

Comment: DO NOT use msql_query() and append values from the webpage, this is known as SQL Injection and it's how your site/database/server gets hacked.  You must use parameterized queries by using PDO instead.

Comment: Thank you Oldskool, I'm new to this so I am really grateful for your patience.
Should I change only this in my code?

mysqli_multi_query($link,$query)

Then change the function Connection to return mysqli?

Comment: What is the datatype in the DB?. I see that `'".$ID2.",'".$ID3.",'".$ID4."'`, after $ID2 you needs add *'* and after $ID3 too.  `VALUES ('".$ID1."','".$ID2."','".$ID3."','".$ID4."','".$ID5."')";`

Comment: @NhanLe See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more information.

Comment: @NhanLe Another thing is that you are accessing to POST variables, but you sends data via GET
`GET /add.php?ID1=1int&ID2=2char&ID3=3char&ID4=4int&ID5=2015-04-13 01:00:00 `
You can change $_POST['var'] by $_GET['var'].

Comment: Hi bquiax, I have updated the datatype of the DB.
For better security, would it be better using $_POST['var'] or $_GET['var']?

Comment: Hi, @NhanLe POST! Therefore you need change the way to test your add.php

Comment: @NhanLe : can you please one of the answer as right. (if one is working for you or helped to fins out).

Comment: @moskito-x I finally made it work, I change everything to $_POST , should I answer the question myself? Or just edit the Question ?

Comment: @NhanLe : $_POST is what we told you all the time. Accept an answer that already exists before you write your own that's only the same describes.

Answer (score 1):

Important part  `$link=Connection();`

- We can not see code of `Connection();`
- your query is wrong
- mentioned in comments -> you using a `http GET` so `$ID1=$_POST["ID1"];` is wrong to.

---

```
'".$ID1."','".$ID2.",'".$ID3.",'".$ID4."','".$ID5."')";
//                  |         |
//                  |_________|____ here forget ' 

$query = "INSERT INTO Battery (ID01, ID02, ID03, ID04, ID05) 
    VALUES ('".$ID1."','".$ID2."','".$ID3."','".$ID4."','".$ID5."')";
```

EDIT

Now we can see in your Edited question

> where ID1,ID4 is int; ID2, ID3 char; ID5 TimeStamp

Query should be (assume TimeStamp ="20150421225300") string format.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Battery (ID01, ID02, ID03, ID04, ID05) 
    VALUES (".$ID1.",'".$ID2."','".$ID3."',".$ID4.",'".$ID5."')";
```

Comment: @NhanLe The request is bad too.

Comment: @NhanLe change too $_POST['var'] by $_GET['var']. Because you sent the data via HTTP GET.

Comment: Hi Moskito, i read somewhere that if I add "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $_POST is ok too,

So, it's not correct?

Comment: We have said so many times. If you are using "http get", then you need to use in the receiving program a $ _GET. If you have a <form> tag you can then with `<form action ="add.php" method = "post ">` a "http post" send. **I would strongly recommend at least to read this.**  [http Get and POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Comment: @NhanLe, using a POST request could be done, but then you will have to send the data in the *POST BODY*, not in the *GET parameters* to get something in $_POST. And , please, never add data in your query this way, this is insecure (plain SQL injection) and not robust at all, various ways of failing. By the way, there's no way for me to upvote an answer containing a query with direct parameters concatenation, right way to hell.

Answer (score 1):

Your http request as you shown in your post (`_` stands for an empty line) :

```
GET /add.php?ID1=1int&ID2=2char&ID3=3char&ID4=4int&ID5=2015-04-13 01:00:00 HTTP/1.1
myhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection:close
_
_
_
```

It is indeed a `bad request` because (a) you have unescaped white space characters in the URI and (b) the second line reads just `myhost` when you probably meant `Host: myhost` (c) you have extra `\r\n` (not likely to cause troubles though), so something like that:

```
POST /add.php?ID1=1int&ID2=2char&ID3=3char&ID4=4int&ID5=2015-04-13+01:00:00 HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection:close
_
_
```

And of course what other said about SQL injections applies.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, I have yet to make the PHP to insert to SQL table correctly. Please have a look at my update, do you have any suggestion?